# Javascript to test if Google reCaptcha exists and is solved

Tags: javascript, iframe, recaptcha, userscripts

I have been struggling trying to figure out how to write some javascript to test if a Google reCaptcha exists and/or is solved. The catch is, I need to be able to run this on any website, not just one that I have access to edit. In other words, a simple user script to test if a Google reCaptcha exists

It can be creative, such as seeing in an element exists, seeing if an object exists, or listening for an event. But I don't know where to start.

The only thing I've got successfully working so far is this, but it's not reliable

```
var element = document.querySelector('[style="visibility: visible; position: absolute; width: 1812px; top: 10px; left: 0px; right: 0px; transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.3s linear; opacity: 1;"]')
```

This grabs the containing div created by reCaptcha.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation specs call for a container Div with  class="g-recaptcha" for the automatic method, which is probably the most common... but if you need a fully modular solution, might not work for you (good for probably most people looking for this answer, and the most direct solution)

```
if($("div.g-recaptcha").length > 0) {
    //captcha *container* exists
} else {
    //There's no container, there should be no captcha
}
```

If using explicit method, and there isn't a clean template you can rely on for container, then you can look at all iframes and look for captcha src. This will work for Automatic implementations as above as well, should be a universal solution.

```
      var captchaExist = false;
      $( "iframe" ).each(function() {
          if($(this).attr('src').substring(0,33) === "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/")
              captchaExist = true;
      });
```

These solutions are using jQuery, but any method of class selector or looping over iframes to check the src would work.

You can't see the content of the iframe, but you can access the attributes of the tag itself.

The key that holds the "solution" (captcha solved) is another container, a hidden textare with ID="g-recaptcha-response"

```
if($("textarea#g-recaptcha-response").val().length > 0) {
    //captcha presumably solved. No guarantee until check on submission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because reCaptcha is in an iframe, and you can't access the content of an iframe from a different origin using JavaScript.

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I'm using electron which allows one to access iframe content. Assuming I can get into the iframe, what should I look for?

Comment: @TMack Use the inspector to find this.